# How to determine if C11 _Generic is supported by the compiler using preprocessor directives?

Tags: generics, keyword, c-preprocessor, language-features, c11

I would like to know if there is any way to determine if support for `_Generic` type-generic macros can be determined for a given compiler using preprocessor directives such as:

`#if __C11_GENERIC_IS_SUPPORTED__ == 1`

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)#Version_detection) mentions a standard version detection macro. I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_Generic` is not an optional feature, so there is no feature test macro. Normally you'd just have to check for the C version that your compiler claims to implement.

Comment: @wap26, can you be a bit more explicit what you think is "wrong" in my answer that you think it deserves a downvote?

Comment: @wap26, the question is about `_Generic`, C11 and nothing else. 1) has nothing to do with `_Generic`, as I said this is not an optional feature. 2) has nothing to do with `_Generic`, either, since that is a C11 feature and not a C99 feature.